# I suspect in someone or I suspect someone (without in)?

Tags: prepositions

What is the right way to say that I suspect (in) someone?

question: "Who took it from here?"

1) I suspect **in** Jon.

b) I suspect Jon.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the validity of the usage of '*in*' in the context, however, you could rephrase the sentence in the following ways:

1. > I suspect Jon.
2. > My suspicion is on Jon.
3. > I'm suspicious about Jon.